# kernel.request event setResponse to RedirectResponse not working

Tags: php, http, events, symfony

I am trying to use the kernel.request event found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-request-event)

A simplified version of my example is to redirect the user unless if they are already on the redirected page. The problem I am seeing is that I am getting a page without any styles - it seems like my styles and js might be redirected as well.

Here is the code

services.yml

```
services:
    app.RequestListener:
        class: App\EventListener\RequestListener
        arguments: [ @security.context ]
        tags:
          - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: redirectUser }
```

requestListener.php

```
class requestListener
{
   public function redirectUser()
   {
      if($event->getRequest()->getPathInfo() != '/') {
         //app_frontend_home_index goes to '/'
         $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_frontend_home_index')));
      }
   }
}
```

I have also tried this where I set ?test=dont_redirect and once that is set it should not redirect

```
   public function redirectUser()
   {
      if(is_null($event->getRequest()->get('test'))) {
         //app_frontend_home_index goes to '/'
         $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_frontend_home_index', array('test' => 'dont_redirect'))));
      }
   }
```

After reading over the section in the link I provided - it sounds like this is the correct event to use. Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up going with. It avoids the need to check the route by making sure the token is not null. To prevent an infinite loop I added in a check for a GET paramter. To complete the example I showed how I am checking if the user has been a member for a longer time than the trial - if so redirect them to the pricing page.

Hopefully this proves useful for someone - if there are any gaps or room for improvement feel free to let me know.

```
public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, Router $router, $trialDays)
{
    $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    $this->router          = $router;
    $this->trialDays       = $trialDays;
}

/**
 * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
 */
public function checkTrial(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if(!is_null($this->securityContext->getToken()) &&
        ($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') || 
        $this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'))) {

        $memberDays = (int)$this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getCreatedAt()->diff(new \DateTime)->format('%d');
        if($memberDays > $this->trialDays &&
           is_null($event->getRequest()->get('redirected'))) {

            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_frontend_pricing_index', array('redirected' => 'true'))));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for the following condition before doing a redirect:

```
if ($event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route')[0] !== '_') {
}
```